# How to setup firewall rules to allow whitelisted IP for communication over eth0

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, ftp, iptables

I have to setup firewall rules for my onboard network(for list of device which are connected via `eth0` interface) during boot up of Linux device.

By default all communication over `eth0` should be disabled.

Then read configuration file (`conf.xml`) which contains ipaddress or URL or port those are only allowed to do communication means only whitelisted devices can do communication.

I have done it in following way but it not works as expected

Default - Disabled `eth0` communication using

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Then For example. enabled FTP access for a Specific IP mentioned in configuration file (`conf.xml`) using below command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

But i see `eth0` communication is permanently disabled and it even not allow ipaddress `10.10.10.10` to access FTP server.

**Edit: As per answer i have modified script as below**

Added below two lines at start

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --dport 21 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --dport 21 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

then added below two lines at the end of script

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

still i am facing issue to access of FTP using IP `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP`

Answer (score 0):

1. iptables rules are processed from top to bottom, and `-A` appends them at the bottom. If you start with a DROP rule that matches *everything,* then those packets will indeed get dropped immediately – they will never go through the subsequent ACCEPTs.

   So make sure your rules are added in the correct order – accept specific things *before* default-dropping everything. (If necessary, use `-I` to insert rules at the top of the chain, rather than bottom.)

   (But once you have a finalized ruleset, save/load the entire ruleset at once using iptables-save and iptables-restore; do not use scripts at that point.)
2. FTP uses more than just port 21 – it uses separate data connections, which (in passive mode) are also inbound to the server, but on various random ports. You need to configure your FTP server for a specific port range and have an iptables ACCEPT rule for it, *in addition* to port 21.

Comment: Thanks sir for ur answer. I followed same procedure as you mention but still i am facing issue. See my updated question. Also can you please elaborate more about FTP uses more then one port? i know that 20 and 21 are used for active and passive connection but what are others and how to configure those?